# Error in `mutate` function when working with tibbles of different data points

Tags: r, dplyr

I think I'm stuck at a pretty simple thing, although I couldn't figure it out myself.

So, I have the following tibbles:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(tibbletime)


symbols_low <- c("TAP", "VLO", "AFL", "ABC", "QCOM", "SWKS", "LRCX","HST","NFLX", "NKE", "AAPL", "SPY")

start_date <- "2016-01-01" 

returns_low <- symbols_low %>% 
  tq_get(get = 'stock.prices', from = start_date, collapse = "monthly", complete_cases = TRUE) %>% 
  select(date, symbol, adjusted) %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  as_tbl_time(index=date) %>% 
  as_period(period = 'monthly', side = 'end') %>% 
  mutate(monthly.returns = log(adjusted) - log(lag(adjusted))) %>% 
  replace_na(list(monthly.returns=0)) %>% 
  mutate(growth = cumprod(1 + monthly.returns)) %>% 
  as_tibble()


wage_growth <- 
  tq_get(
    x = 'A576RC1',
    get = 'economic.data',
    collapse = 'monthly',
    from = start_date) %>% 
  select(date, price) %>% 
  mutate (monthly_increase = (price - lag(price))/lag(price)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(monthly_increase=0)) %>% 
  mutate (wage_index = cumprod (1 + monthly_increase)) %>% 
  mutate (wage_lag_3 = lag(monthly_increase, 3)) %>% 
  mutate (wage_lag_6 = lag(monthly_increase, 6)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(date <= "2021-07-01")
```

I tried to create a new tibble `returns_wages_low`, but got the following error message.

```
returns_wages_low <- 
  returns_low %>% 
  dplyr::filter(date <= "2021-06-01") %>% 
  mutate(wage_change = wage_growth$monthly_increase,
         wage_index = wage_growth$wage_index, 
         wage_lag_3 = wage_growth$wage_lag_3,
         wage_lag_6 = wage_growth$wage_lag_6) %>% 
  as_tibble()

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `wage_change`.
ℹ `wage_change = wage_growth$monthly_increase`.
ℹ `wage_change` must be size 780 or 1, not 65.
```

A problem may be related to a tibble `returns_low`, that consists of the data in a long format. The tibble has more data points than the `wage_growth` tibble. A tibble `returns_low` contains 67 data points for each of the 12 tickers selected (804 in total). At the same time, tibble `wage_growth` contains 65 data points. I suspect, that the source of the error may be inconsistency between these tibbles.

I would appreciate your inputs in solving the issue. Thank all in advance.

Comment: Could you also, please, add the packages that you are using?

Comment: @Serkan, sure. Made changes to the post.

Comment: Does akruns answer not answer your question?

Comment: Yes, he did answer it. However, a new issue popped up related to consistency of the date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we need a `left_join` instead of extracting the column with `$` as the datasets are obviously not having the same dimensions (that is complicated again after `filter`ing)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibbletime)
library(tidyquant)
returns_low %>% 
  dplyr::filter(date <= "2021-06-01") %>% 
  left_join(wage_growth) %>% 
   rename(wage_change = monthly_increase)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 780 x 10
   date       symbol adjusted monthly.returns growth price wage_change wage_index wage_lag_3 wage_lag_6
   <date>     <chr>     <dbl>           <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2016-01-29 TAP        81.2         0        1        NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 2 2016-02-29 TAP        76.6        -0.0593   0.941    NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 3 2016-03-31 TAP        86.8         0.125    1.06     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 4 2016-04-29 TAP        86.3        -0.00573  1.05     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 5 2016-05-31 TAP        89.5         0.0364   1.09     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 6 2016-06-30 TAP        91.6         0.0235   1.12     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 7 2016-07-29 TAP        92.5         0.0101   1.13     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 8 2016-08-31 TAP        93.1         0.00560  1.13     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
 9 2016-09-30 TAP        99.9         0.0706   1.21     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
10 2016-10-31 TAP        94.4        -0.0561   1.15     NA          NA         NA         NA         NA
# … with 770 more rows
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. It worked. However, another issue popped up, that is related to dates in datasets. I need `returns_low` to show values at the end of the period (that's why `side = 'end'`), but data in the `wage_growth` dataset are for the beginning of the same period. That's why we get NAs when `left_join`. I'm not sure if there is a way to somehow solve this issue as it concerns dates consistency.

Comment: I found a solution by creating a separate date vector with date points similar to the `return_wages_low` data set. They are very much close to each other with 1-2 days difference.

Comment: @dkolkin do you need `inner_join`

Comment: I don’t think this will work because the two date variables contain no identical date points. So, I found a simple solution to adjust the date variable in a ‘wage_growth’ data set to make it the same as in ‘returns_low’. This approach worked for me.

Comment: @dkolkin how you are adjusting the date variable.  I didn't understand.

Comment: @dkolkin Arre you changing the `start_date`

Comment: I just change the date column in a wage_growth with a new one, that was manually created. Since FRED reports payouts of wages for the past month in the beginning of the following month, I just changed dates from the beginning of current month to the end of the previous one.